# How can I build a corpus from unstructured text (pdf, txt, html) and train IBM Watson? And then ask questions via API calls?

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-watson

I want to train a machine learning system such as IBM Watson using some PDF, txt, html unstructured data, and then ask questions and get answers via API calls. How can I achieve that? GUI based training or API based training. From Bluemix, it is hard to decide which service is best to achieve this requirement. Can you please suggest the best options?

Answer (score 1):

**Retrieve and Rank**- Retrieve and Rank can surface the most relevant information from a collection of documents. For example, using R&R, an experienced technician can quickly find solutions from dense product manuals. A contact center agent can also quickly find answers to improve average call handle times. The Retrieve and Rank service works "out of the box," but can also be customized to improve the results. More details [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/retrieve-rank.html)

**Discovery Service**- Extract value from unstructured data by converting, normalizing, enriching it. Use a simplified query language to explore that data or to quickly tap into pre-enriched datasets like the Discovery News collection. More details [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Watson Discovery (https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/discovery) for your purpose. 
It's very complete and supports many features in both GUI and API. It supports questions in natural language or in query format.

Its documentation is here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/getting-started.html#getting-started-with-the-api

If you create a free instance of Watson Discovery, you can test its API here: https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/discovery-v1

There are examples of each API call here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/

There is also a demo and respective code here: 
https://discovery-news-demo.mybluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=30407807098515090430617&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1509636542&cm_mc_sid_52640000=1509636542 
and 
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/discovery-nodejs